# How to grab a list of only active calls and active queues from Twilio

Tags: twilio

How do i grab only active queues while incoming call to my twilio number.Is there any way to filter only latest queues and update those queues order.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I guess this depends on what you mean by "Active".  If you mean, Queues that have calls waiting in them, there is not currently a way to have Twilio give you just that list.

You can ask Twilio to give you a list of Queues and then your application can filter that list using the *[CurrentSize](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue#instance-properties)* parameter.

If you want to dequeue callers in a order other than the default FIFO behavior seen when you `<Dial>` a call into a `<Queue>`, you can use the REST API to dequeue a specific call:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/member#instance-post-example-2

If that still does not give you enough control for your scenario you can always fall back to using a simple `<Conference>` instead of a `<Queue>`.  In that case you would add calls to a conference in a muted state, and your application would be responsible for tracking what calls are in the conference, how long they have waited and what order they arrived.

Hope that helps.  If I've misunderstood what you mean by Active, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Devin, Thanks for answered and "Active" means calls those are in queue and wait for next calls. That is your are absolutely right Calls waiting . I want to list all list my calls which are waiting in queues and shuffle( change) their queue order. Let say there are 5 phone number are in queues waiting for calls in order to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. and i don't want to pick up 1 first call and put 1 order queues to last and pickup 2 order to first order of queues and vice-verse.  Is that possible?.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Hopefully its the info your looking for.